# Problema al cargar combo box con datos de bd mysql

Tags: mysql, jsp

**Estimados**

Buenos tardes, estoy intentando cargar un combo box con datos de una bd mysql
el problema es que los datos se ven pero se duplican los combo box.

Acá dejo el código jsp con el combo box

```
<%
 Folio fl=new Folio();

 Connection conn = ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();

 FoliosDao fdao=new FoliosDao();

 ResultSet res=(ResultSet)fdao.listarNumeroFoliosReservas(fl);
 ArrayList<Folio> numFolio = new ArrayList<Folio>();

    if(res==null)
    {
      String error="No se encontraron datos";
      request.getSession().setAttribute("error", error);
    }

    else
      {
        try
          {
            while(res.next())
          {

            numFolio.add(new Folio(res.getInt("cod_seq_awb"),res.getString("awb")));

          }
            request.getSession().setAttribute("numFolio", numFolio);

            ArrayList<Folio> fo = (ArrayList<Folio>)request.getSession().getAttribute("numFolio");

             for(int i=0; i<fo.size(); i++)
                {
                    out.println("<select class='form-control'>");
                    out.println("<option>Seleccione Folio</option>");
                    out.println("<option>"+fo.get(i).getNumeroFolioCompleto()+"</option>");
                    out.println("</select>");
                }
          }
         catch(SQLException ex)
          {
             ex.getMessage();
          }
      }
%>
```

Acá el metodo de la clase FoliosDao del paquete dao que es el que tiene la consulta sql.

```
    public ResultSet listarNumeroFoliosReservas(Folio f)
{
    try {
        Connection conn=ConexionMysqlCargomove_db.getInstance().getConnection();
        st=(Statement)conn.createStatement();
        String SQL="";

        SQL="select a.cod_seq_awb,a.awb from awb a, rvas r\n" +
            "where a.cod_seq_awb=r.awb_cod_seq_awb;";
        res=st.executeQuery(SQL);


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FoliosDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex.getStackTrace());
    }
    return res;
}
```

Lo que yo necesito ver en el combo box es el listado de folios pero me los muestra con los combo box duplicados y como en la bd hay 11 registros, me trae los 11 pero duplicando los combobox un registro por combo.
Acá imágenes del problema.
Como puedo solucionar ese problema?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me parece que el error se encuentra acá:

```
for(int i=0; i<fo.size(); i++)
 {
  out.println("<select class='form-control'>");
  out.println("<option>Seleccione Folio</option>");
  out.println("<option>"+fo.get(i).getNumeroFolioCompleto()+"</option>");
  out.println("</select>");
 }
```

Dentro del ciclo for creas tanto el control como las opciones, debes crear fuera del for el control y dentro del for las opciones:

```
out.println("<select class='form-control'>");
out.println("<option>Seleccione Folio</option>");

for(int i=0; i<fo.size(); i++)
 {
  out.println("<option>"+fo.get(i).getNumeroFolioCompleto()+"</option>");
 }

out.println("</select>");
```

Comment: Siii eso era muchas gracias.